# Kafka Streams - Convert Expression to Single Abstract Method

Tags: scala, apache-kafka-streams

I am building an application using Kafka Streams with Scala. In it, I have a use case where I have to apply `map()` on a `KStream`.

Since Kafka Streams does not provide a Scala API, so, I have to write `map` function like this:

```
val builder = new KStreamBuilder()
val originalStream = builder.stream("SourceTopic")

val mappedStream =
  originalStream.map[String, Integer] {
    new KeyValueMapper[String, String, KeyValue[String, Integer]] {
      override def apply(key: String, value: String): KeyValue[String, Integer] = {
        new KeyValue(key, new Integer(value.length))
      }
    }
  }
```

Above code compiles/runs fine. But, gives a warning - `Convert Expression to Single Abstract Method`.

So, my question is to how to convert above map expression into a SAM?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Well you can of-course also do:
```originalStream.map[String, Integer]((x, y) => new KeyValue(x, y.length))```. 
Of-course you would have to be on scala 2.12.x

Comment: @Jatin I am using Scala 2.11.8.

Comment: Unfortunately for 2.11.x, you would need to explicitly create anonymous class

Comment: That's disappointing!